# Can the expect script stops the execution if the expr doesnt match

Tags: perl, expect

In expect module if the expression I am expecting is not matching, how to stop the execution of the program and come out of the loop.Because, even if the pattern doesn't match it goes on executing the script.

ex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
use Expect;    
my $handle = new Expect;    
$handle = Expect->spawn("telnet 192.168.1.1");    
$handle->expect(10,'re','sdhj: ');     #The expected string [sdhj: ]is not matching , but even then it goes on executing the below lines    
$handle->send("system\r");    
$handle->expect(10,'re','Password: ');    
$handle->send("12345\r");
```

What I want is, if the expression expected is not matched, then execution of the program should be stopped with error msg.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple case like this just add an `or die` where you want the error message to occur (change my error message below to whatever you want):

```
$handle->expect(10,'re','sdhj: ') or die "Didn't match [sdhj: ] $!"
```

If things get a little more complicated you might want to look into the [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) module.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
my $timeout = 10;
my $pattern = 'sdhj:';
$handle->expect($timeout,
                'timeout', sub {die "did not match $pattern in $timeout seconds"},
                '-re',$pattern
);
```

Documentation: https://metacpan.org/module/RGIERSIG/Expect-1.21/Expect.pod#object-expect-timeout-match_patterns